# How to define dynamic-shape variable when building computational graph with Tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, dynamic, eager-execution

**System information**

1. Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): No
2. OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux Ubuntu 18.04
3. Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device:
4. TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Conda repo
5. TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.15
6. Python version: 3.7.7
7. Bazel version (if compiling from source):
8. GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source):
9. CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.1
10. GPU model and memory: Tesla V100-SMX3-32GB
11. Describe the current behavior

    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [] rhs shape= [1,1]
    [[{{node Variable/Assign}}]]

**Describe the expected behavior**

No error

**Standalone code to reproduce the issue**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]='0'

with tf.Session() as sess:
    v = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape=[1,1]),shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Obseration:
The error did not appear when I use eager_execution_mode()

Code:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
v = tf.Variable(np.zeros([1,1]),shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
tf.print(v)
v.assign(np.ones([2,2]))
tf.print(v)
```

Output:

```
[[0]]
[[1 1]
 [1 1]]
```

**Link to a MWE:** https://colab.research.google.com/gist/amahendrakar/3fe8345db4092d520246205be4b97948/41620.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Just have to enable resource variable as dynamic shape behavior is only available for this 'updated' Variable class.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]='0'
tf.compat.v1.enable_resource_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    v = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape=[1,1]),shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```